# How is Analects split up in English? Chapters? Verses?

Tags: translation

Apparently Analects is made up of:

> 《论语》共20篇，492章

in Chinese.

The first "chapter" as it is called in English is:

> 学而第一 16章

said to have sixteen 章.

This is the English index:

[image: index]

and the first chapter:

[image: chapter one]

So, in English if it's chapter one, what is 1-16 of chapter one? Verses? Sentences? Phrases?

or would book / chapter be more appropriate? book 1 / chapter 1?

Comment: not quite understand the question.....

Comment: Chinese is 篇章 what's the English equivalent way that Analects is split up? Chapters?

Comment: sections? maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with the Bible, I think Book/Chapter would be the most accurate.  Each 篇 revolves around one specific aspect of Confucius' ideas, and each 章 is a (mostly self-contained) event/story.

Unlike the Bible, in which the chapters/stories usually follow a chronological order within one book, there is little interdependence between chapters in 论语.  But I would argue that, if one is to extract Jesus's words from each chapter of Bible, one would probably get something of size comparable to a 章.  Therefore it is quite reasonable to make 篇/章 correspond to Book/Chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The Analects is a collection of articles, with 20 articles in total. The first article Xue Er has 16 Chapters.

If you take a look at [this version](http://www.cnculture.net/ebook/jing/sishu/lunyu_en/), it translates articles into "book"s.

Comment: those make for mighty small chapters

Comment: True. Our ancestors loved to write short stuff. 文言文 is quite short, poems are very short too :)